# MEAN Stack Cannot Update MongoDB Record using PUT method

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

Cannot update mongoDB record, using PUT method. Parameters are passing correctly, there must be a problem within a query I guess.

**Schema**

```
let Boards = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    lastUploaded: Number,
    owner_id: String
});
```

**Server:**

```
module.exports.updateTime = function (req, res) {
    let board = new Board();
    let id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id);
    let myquery = { _id: id };
    let newvalues = { lastUploaded: req.body.time };
    console.log("New time: " + req.body.time); //Number recieved
    console.log("Id: " + req.body._id); //String recieved
    board.findByIdAndUpdate(myquery, newvalues, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            response = { success: false, message: "Error updating data" };
        } else {
            response = { success: true, message: "Data updated" };
        }
        res.json(response);
    });
    board.close();
};
```

**Client:**

```
public updateTime(updateOptions: UpdateTime): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers;
        let URI = `${apiUrl}/updateTime`;
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.put(URI, updateOptions, { headers: headers })
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Router:**

```
router.put('/updateTime', ctrlContent.updateTime);
```

[image: **Error Picture**]

Finally gave me empty response error through `.catch(this.handleError);`

Comment: Can you post the put url ? when you PUT did you pass the id in the url ? also console.log(req.body)

Comment: This doesn't look like a complete example.  Where is the route?  What happens in the findByIdAndUpdate  callback?  It looks ok.

Comment: @RobertMoskal through the browser network inspect request is not finished yet. So it cannot pass through findByIdAndUpdate.

Comment: What is he value of `err`?

Comment: @willmaz console.log(req.body) gives all passed parameters, that's not a problem. Seems like issue is with findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: @torazaburo no value there, cause it doesn't reach to this point, smth doesn't let finish the request

Comment: Make sur that lastUploaded is defined in your Board schema , and try passing the id directly : findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, ...)  rather than { _id: id }

Comment: @willmaz yes, lastUploaded is a part of the schema and I tried to pass id as an object, req.body._id and as a mongoose ObjectId type. Didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs that I can see.

First, the first argument to the `findByIdAndUpdate` method should be an _id itself, not an object with an _id property:

```
// this will not work
board.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, newvalues, handler);

// this is how it should be
board.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, newvalues, handler);
```

Second, you are calling `board.close();` outside of the query callback. Closing a connection is propably a mistake, but even if you absolutely need it, you should do it inside the callback function.

Here is a complete server example:

```
module.exports.updateTime = function (req, res) {
    let id = req.body._id;
    let newvalues = { lastUploaded: req.body.time };

    Board.findByIdAndUpdate(id, newvalues, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: "Error updating data" });
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: "Data updated" });
        }
    });
};
```